# Metro UI Transparency

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
p  {
 font-color: white;
}

/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-*/
/* Column Grids */
/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= */

.col_half { width: 49%; }
.col_third { width: 32%; }
.col_second { width: 32%; }
.col_fourth { width: 23.5%; }
.col_fifth { width: 18.4%; }
.col_sixth { width: 15%; }
.col_seventh {
    position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 29%;
 margin-bottom: -90px; }
.col_eight {
    position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 29%;
 padding: 0px; margin-bottom: -130px;}
 
 .col_n { width: 32%; }
 
.col_three_fourth { width: 74.5%;}
.col_twothird{ width: 66%;}
.col_half,
.col_third,
.col_twothird,
.col_fourth,
.col_three_fourth,
.col_fifth{
 position: relative;
 display:inline;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: -5%;
 margin-bottom: -40px;
}
.end { margin-right: 0 !important; }
.up {margin-top: -160px !important;}
.down {margin-top: 100px !important;}
.n {margin-left: 810px; margin-top: 100px; padding-left: 150px; padding-top: 10px !important;}
.x {margin-left: 469px; overflow: hidden !important; margin-top: -180px; padding-left: 60px;  padding-top: 10px;}


/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */
/* Flip Panel */
/*-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=- */

.wrapper{ width: 980px; margin: 0 auto;  background-color: #fff; overflow: hidden; float: left; padding-top: 10px;}

.panel {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 200px;  
 position: center;
 -webkit-perspective: 600px;
 -moz-perspective: 600px;
}

.panel .front,
.panel .back {
 text-align: center;
}
 
.panel .front {
 height: inherit;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 900;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.panel .back {
 height: inherit;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.panel.flip .front {
 z-index: 900;
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.panel.flip .back {
 z-index: 1000;
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
}
.box1{
 background-color: #CBC5C1;
 background-size: 200px ;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 top: 0px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 45px;
}
.box2{
 background-color: #CBC5C1;
 width: 250px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 18px;

}

.box3{
 background-color: #A2AAB0;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 110px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;

}
.box4{
 background-image: url("../img/feathers.png");
 background-size: 150px 120px;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
}
.box5{
 background-image: url("../img/fallingleaves.gif");
 background-size: 550px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 width: 515px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 50px;

}
.box6{
 background-image: url("../img/fallingleaves.gif");
 background-size:550px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 width: 515px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 50px;

}
.box7{
 background-image: url("../img/dateandtime.jpg");
 background-size:250px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 margin-bottom: 300px;
 padding: 1px;
 padding-right: 80px;

}
.box8{
 background-size: 290px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: white;
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;

}
.box9{
 background-color: #4C586F;
 width: 250px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 45px;

}
.box10{
 background-image: url("../img/commended/nes.png");
 background-size: 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 250px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 12px;

}

.box11{
 background-color: #EBECED;
 width: 250px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px;
 
}
.box12{
 background-color: #EBECED;
 width: 250px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px;

}
.box13{
 background-color: #4C586F;
 width: 200px;
 height: 310px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px;
 
}
.box14{
 background-color: #4C586F;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 35px;

}
.box15{
 background-color: #4C586F;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 40px;
 
}
```

I have this Metro UI on my website which looks like this:

[image]

And when you hover on it, it would flip and would show this:

[image]

The problem is I have another Metro UI which looks like this:

[image]

The front should be Time and Date and the back should be a weather forecast. The problem is that the front shows the backside (weather forecast).

```css
.box7 {
  background-image: url("../img/dateandtime.jpg");
  background-size: 250px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  padding: 1px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.box8 {
  background-size: 290px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col_seventh up">
  <div class="hover panel">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="box7">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <iframe src="https://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i5x43ph0/n145/fn6/fs20/tt0/tw0/tm1/tb4" frameborder="0" width="128" height="50" style="position: relative; left: 37px;"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="box8">
        <iframe id="forecast_embed" frameborder="0" height="280" width="100%" src="https://forecast.io/embed/#lat=14.4184&lon=121.0385&name=Manila&color=#00aaff&font=Century%20Gothic&units=uk"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: Sorry for my english

Comment: I've merged your HTML and CSS in to a runnable snippet. Please edit the code so that it shows the problem that you describe.

Comment: @Turnip What do you mean? I've already put all the codes needed.

Comment: When I press the run button the result looks nothing like your example image. There is also nothing in the CSS that you have posted that would flip the element when hovered.

Comment: @Turnip Oh sorry, I added the whole CSS code.

Comment: If instead of using transitions, you could use keyframes, then you could hide the back side to begin with and at the half way point (where it's "side-on" to the viewer and therefor invisible) swap the visibility.

Comment: @DBS So change all "transform" to "keyframe"?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not quite that simple, you would need to write the rotate animation yourself, though as you're only changing a single transform property it shouldn't be too complex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: @DBS I understand. The weird thing tho is that I have 6 Metro UIs and that's the only one that isn't working properly. The other 5 is working properly.

Comment: I imagine the others all have a background colour. I assumed you needed the transparency, but if not you could simply give your `.front` and `.back` a `background-color`, which would hide the problem.